# Embed chat in web application

Tags: java, gwt, livechat

I have my existing gwt web application running and deployed properly Now I want to embed the chat in my application. How should i go about it? Is there any easy way, or sample which i can just add as an api and start using the chat application?  My web application have the goggle authentication enabled so i want to have all the user who are logged in my application to chat with each other.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Because you wanne embed it it's gonna be that easy...please see https://developers.google.com/talk/?hl=nl